# View freezes when returning to OnResume on Android 6.0 Tab

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This issue occurs only on Android 6.0 Tablet.

I use `fileObserver` to get the saved Image Path and display that image in my app and Firebase ML kit to check the readability of the text present in that image.

I first open the third party app to capture image for my app and as soon as I click a picture, a background thread is spawned and a progress bar with text messaage is shown in the UI.

Once firebase ML kit finishes it's job, the result whether the document is readable or not is then saved in an object.

Now as soon as I close the third party app and return to my app(`onResume()`), the code executes to set the image on ImageView and hide progressbar, but UI is freezed with progress bar and the UI updates only when I click anywhere on the screen.

```
public class DocFragment extends Fragment{
   private FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(LENS_DIR_PATH) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
             if (event == CLOSE_WRITE) {
                  String attachedImagePath = LENS_DIR_PATH + path;
//                Log.v(TAG, "File was saved: " + LENS_DIR_PATH + path);

                  processDoc(attachedImagePath);
             }
        }
  };

  @Override
  public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        observer.startWatching();

  }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        observer.stopWatching();

    }
}
```

```
    class DocProvider {

        fun processDoc(path: String) {
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
                semaphore.acquire()
              activity.runOnUiThread {
                  showProgressBar()
              }
            }
            // Image processing and updating the result after showing Progress Bar 
            updateResult()
        }

        private fun updateResult() {
            docResult.updateResult()
            semaphore.release()
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have Java and Kotlin in the same file??

Comment: They are not in the same file. I have made some changes. Please check.